# How do I get into a Computer Science Masters with a humanities undergraduate degree?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, career-path, computer-science

I realize my question is similar to [this thread](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12580/how-do-i-get-into-a-computer-science-masters-without-an-undergrad-in-cs). However, I have a slightly different story which I'd like to ask people's opinion about.

I have a Bachelor of Arts degree in East Asian Studies (specialist) and History (minor). I graduated in the middle of the latest economic slump and wasn't able to find jobs in my field. Since I have been an avid computer geek from a very young age, I decided to leverage those skills and ended up becoming a tech support consultant, sys-admin, and am currently a full-stack web developer.

In a way, I don't really require getting a Computer Science masters degree as I've been in the field now for about 5 years. On the other hand, not having that extra piece of paper has impeded me from being strongly credible as well as from obtaining better paying jobs.

**Question:**  Given my experience in the field already, how likely is it for me to get accepted for a Computer Science masters degree with my B.A. undergraduate degree?

Comment: The answer would probably depend on the nature of the program that you want to apply to. In a graduate program in straight computer science, lack of a background in things like discrete mathematics, algorithmic complexity, computer language theory, etc. would probably be a serious (but not insurmountable) impediment. On the other hand, in a graduate program with a more applied bent, your work experience might count for a great deal. Also -- with your background, a masters in Computer Information Science (some of which will concentrate on web application development) might be a natural fit.